# Not getting correct length with unrecognized chars

Tags: groovy

I am calculating the length in Groovy with the below code and it works fine. But, when the name field contains unrecognized characters (highlighted) it is giving incorrect length. Please advise.

**Input Data:**

```
{"groupId":"5jb878adfs0k1fnzh4ijlvndi","caseId":"V12900","name":"EAE TEKNOLOJİ ARAŞTIRMA GELİŞTİRME SAN.VE TİC.A.Ş","providerTypes":["WATCHLIST"],
"entityType":"ORGANISATION","secondaryFields":[{"value":"ARE","typeId":"SFCT_6"}]}
```

**Groovy Script**

```
byte[] arr = jsonBody.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
String s = new String (arr);    
j = s.length(); 
jlen = Integer.toString(j);
```

Comment: Can you try specifying the encoding when you change it back to the string (after changing a string to bytes?!) `String s = new String(arr, "UTF-8")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply . the string should return the length as 235 instead giving 228. we have checked in POSMAN . thus failing to authenticate the API. I have changed as per your suggesting but no luck .   byte[] arr = jsonBody.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
//String s = new String (arr); 
String s = new String(arr, "UTF-8")
j = s.length(); 
jlen = Integer.toString(j);

Comment: But `Ş` is a single character represented by 2 bytes in UTF-8:`0xC5 0x9E`

Comment: Name field value - EAE TEKNOLOJİ ARAŞTIRMA GELİŞTİRME SAN.VE TİC.A.Ş

Comment: Yes. That's 49 utf8 characters, totaling 56 bytes.